# Is there any push-button off-on switch?

Tags: arduino, switches, surface-mount

I have the following problem, I need to use a pushbutton that is of the switch type on / off, but I do not get any since all are of momentary action and I need one that maintains the state until I press it again. This type of switch exists? I have doubts about it.
I got this, but I have the doubt if it is of momentary action. https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Mountain-Switch/101-0464-EV/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsgGjVA3toVBOvQBfIqAaeKOkMmYcOfYg8%3d
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not in that format. There is only so much you can do in such a tight space. You would need to add circuitry to do that. Have it toggle a flip-flop type circuit.

Comment: There are hundreds of push-on push-off switches such as this: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mec-switches/15451/679-1961-ND/2034517     ....if you want bigger switches there's an even larger range, it's a very common switch function.

Comment: You want a switch of unknown current capacity, unknown mounting type, and unknown size, but it has to be a push on/off?

Comment: I need a switch preferably SMD, of reduced size and to work only with CC and specifically to work with Arduino

Answer (score 1):

That switch is in the catalog section "All Products > Electromechanical > Switches > **Tactile Switches** > Mountain Switch 101-0464-EV". Tactile switches are usually designed for keyboard entry with a tactile click or snap action to give touch feedback that they have changed status. Early calculators didn't have tactile switches and were very prone to data entry errors with missing or double-keystrokes.

[image]

An image search for [tactile+latching+switch](https://www.google.ie/search?q=tactile+latching+switch) throws up plenty of results. In general they seem a bit taller than the momentary action type but this is to be expected as the latching mechanism has to be incorporated.

As always heed the EE.SE site advice: "no datasheet - no sale".

Comment: it means that this switch (Mountain Switch 101-0464-EV) that I have placed here does not work, that it does not fulfill this function. The truth is that I can not get a switch that meets what I need